# os.kill in for loop throws exception

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I have a for loop which opens a application with `subprocess.Popen` and closes it with `os.kill`.

Whole code:

```
import subprocess
import time
import signal
import os

with open('programs.txt') as f:
    programs = f.readlines()

programs = [x.strip() for x in programs] 

for program in programs: 
    programOpened = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\\path\\to\\application\\" + program])
    time.sleep(5)

    os.kill(programOpened.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

This throws for my this exception:

```
os.kill(programOpened.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) 
SystemError: <built-in function kill> returned a result with an error set
```

Why is this exception thrown and how could i close a subprocess in a for loop?

Comment: why not just `programOpened.terminate()` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, presumably the application has a Ctrl+C handler that tries to exit gracefully. `terminate()` forcefully kills the process, akin to a Unix `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Note that the upvoted answer on the linked question is misleading and wrong on several points. I'll edit it later if I have time and remember to do so. This particular error is a bug in `os.kill`, which even without bugs is one of the most poorly thought out functions in Windows CPython. It should have been split into `os.killpg` and `os.kill`, based on `GenerateConsolCtrlEvent` and `TerminateProcess`, respectively.

Comment: @eryksun yeah, that's what I thought afterwards. I hope you agree with the duplicate.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I thought your answer was good, it helped my.

Comment: you mean the duplicate link? it's a duplicate either way. Glad I could help.

Comment: no I meant your answer, the duplicate link is way to specific for my question.

Comment: Okay, well... all good then :) added another dupe linik for good measure